# Azure VNet Peerings - Failed to add virtual network peering between Azure Databricks VNet and Azure VM VNet

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-virtual-machine, vnet

At the beginning, I went to Azure Databricks VNet Peerings to create VNet Peering between the ADB VNet (created by default. I didn't create the ADB in my own VNet) and the Azure VM VNet.

Both resources are under the same region and same resource group.
ADB is in the East US.
Azure VM is in East US (Zone 1)

The Peering from Azure VM VNet to ADB VNet was successfully created. And the peering status is initiated.

But the peering from ADB VNet to Azure VM failed.

Below is the error message:
`The access is denied because of the deny assignment with the name 'System deny assignment created by Azure Databricks`

I followed the steps for adding remote VNet peering to the ADB VNet in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/network/classic/vnet-peering.

Please guide me to create a peering with connected status between Azure Databricks VNet and Azure VM VNet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created databricks and virtual machine in same location and same resource group. Peered vm to databricks same successfully like below:

[image]

```
Failed to add virtual network peering 'peering-databrick-vm' to 'workers-vnet'. Error: The client 'XXXXXX has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/write' on scope 'workers-vnet/peering-databrick-vm'; however, the access is denied because of the deny assignment with name 'System deny assignment created by Azure Databricks
```

This issue occurs when you trying to peer Managed Resource Group -> workers vnet to peer vnet from data bricks to vm check the below:

In your databricks  -> virtual network peering -> select your vnet -> Allow forwarded traffic like below:

[image]

Once you peered in your Managed Resource Group -> workers vnet you can see their peered status like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I successfully created the connected Perring after I created 1 Peering in the `worker-vnet` and 1 Peering in the VM vnet.